# rails custom route for model with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm having trouble defining a Rails 'new' route for a model that takes a param to another model to which it will be linked. We have a legacy URL structure in place, so unfortunately 
a nested `resource` route won't work here.

I'd like to define the "create a new review" URL as `/reviews/new/1234`, where `1234` is the `book_id` that the soon-to-be-created `Review` should reference.

My routes (snipped for brevity) are defined as:

```
get    '/reviews/:book_id'          => 'reviews#index',   :as => 'reviews_path'
get    '/reviews/new/:book_id', :to => 'reviews#new',     :as => 'new_review_path'
post   '/reviews/:book_id'          => 'reviews#create'
get    '/reviews/:book_id/:id'      => 'reviews#show'
get    '/reviews/:book_id/:id/edit' => 'reviews#edit',    :as => 'edit_review_path'
delete '/reviews/:book_id/:id'      => 'reviews#destroy'
```

`rake routes | grep review` returns:

```
      reviews_path GET    /reviews/:book_id(.:format)                                              reviews#index
   new_review_path GET    /reviews/new/:book_id(.:format)                                          reviews#new
                   POST   /reviews/:book_id(.:format)                                              reviews#create
                   GET    /reviews/:book_id/:id(.:format)                                          reviews#show
  edit_review_path GET    /reviews/:book_id/:id/edit(.:format)                                     reviews#edit
                   DELETE /reviews/:book_id/:id(.:format)                                      reviews#destroy
```

In my view template I have:

```
<%= link_to 'new review', new_review_path(book_id: @book.id) %>
```

which fails with:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `new_review_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f818f7117c8>:0x007f818f70e208>):
```

For completeness, my `Review` model looks like:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessible :book_id, :title, :content, :tags
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `_path` from the end of the `:as` conditions on your routes.  Right now it's looking for `new_review_path_path`.

Documentation [is here for using as](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-as-in-nested-resources).

Comment: No worries man - I have the markdown syntax for facepalm.jpg as a macro as I use it several times an hour, so I don't remember. :)  Sometimes you just need extra SO eyes.